# Elastic css framework with rails 3 and haml/sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass, fluid

I recently stumbled upon "elastic css" framework, which looks like a good thing to me. I tried blueprint already but I must say this seems to be an overkill for me (tried it with compass).

So my question to you rails/xhtml webdevelopers out there: Is the elastic css framework together with rails (3) and haml/sass a good thing? ;)

I searched the www but did not even find if elastic css can be used together with sass and haml - anyone has experience with that? Maybe there is also something as simple as fluid css out there? Are there any recommendations?

Thanks!

FYI: http://elasticss.com

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about ports of this exact 'Elastic CSS Framework', but Susy is a framework built native to Compass/Sass that handles any combination of static, fluid and elastic grids - specializing in Natalie Downe's Elastic-Fluid technique:

http://susy.oddbird.net/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:
https://github.com/marnen/compass-elastic-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The main difference on Elastic CSS Framework is that you don't need to port it to Sass/Haml,
because its not a grid system its a layout framework. We have tried using elastic, rails 2.3, and haml, sass. not for very big things but definitely works.

It actually should work in all cases because you would be using sass only for skinning your site, you don't need to do any layout, you can let elastic do that, and all paddings, backgrounds, colors and stuff, you can do that in sass without problems.

Like elastic uses classes, haml is not a problem at all. and you don't really need to use divs only, you can apply the classes from elastic to any element.

So, you should try it out, and we are happy to help anyone on the [elasticss group at google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/elastic-css-framework).